# Hyperledger Fabric - Join peer from another host

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-swarm

My setup is the following:

- 2 Linux virtual machines running in VirtualBox;
- Both hosts are engaged in a Docker Swarm;
- Host 1 consists of: 1 orderer, 1 organization with 2 peers and a cli container;
- Host 2 consists of: 1 organization with 2 peers;
- I'm using the following tutorial as reference (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org)

How I'm actually running the Fabric network:

1. I'm generating the channel artifacts & crypto-config files the same on both hosts.
2. Starting fabric on host 2 - with both peers, couchdbs and ca;
3. Starting fabric on host 1;
4. Generating a channel on host 1; joining peers from host 1 and updating anchor peer;
5. When inspecting the overlay swarm network I'm able to see both peers and containers available for each host;

My problems appear when trying to make the peers from host 2 join the channel. I'm trying to add them to the channel through the cli on host 1.

But I'm receiving the following error:

```
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.sponsor.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
```

This is my docker-compose-cli.yaml for host 1:

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.example.com:
  peer0.manager.example.com:
  peer1.manager.example.com:
  peer0.sponsor.example.com:
  peer1.sponsor.example.com:

networks:
  example:

services:

  orderer.example.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base-1.yaml
      service: orderer.example.com
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - example

  peer0.manager.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.manager.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base-1.yaml
      service: peer0.manager.example.com
    networks:
      - example

  peer1.manager.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.manager.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base-1.yaml
      service: peer1.manager.example.com
    networks:
      - example

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.manager.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=ManagerMSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/manager.example.com/peers/peer0.manager.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/manager.example.com/peers/peer0.manager.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/manager.example.com/peers/peer0.manager.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/manager.example.com/users/Admin@manager.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.manager.example.com
      - peer1.manager.example.com

    networks:
      - example
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a very simple mistake: I was not copying the generated crypto material from one host to another; I was generating new crypto materials on all of the hosts, thinking that they will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The node fails to connect to **peer0.sponsor.proa.com**. This is probably due to some changes you have made to customize the network addresses to your liking, is this something you've customized? I haven't followed this tutorial but I've run into some similar problems while customizing the first-network example while following [this one](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html).

Make sure your peer addresses are well configured on the **configtx.yaml, cryptoconfig.yaml**, **docker-compose-cli.yaml** and **docker-compose-base.yaml** and also **peer-base.yaml** if you changed the network name.

If the addresses of the peers don't check out accross those files you will probably need to generate the channel transactions again and start the network over, since the configuration for the channel that is present in the blockchain is not matching your current network configuration.

Comment: Peer0.org1 and Peer1.org1 are at 7051 & 8051 on host 1 and the same for org2... I've looked closely to the overall configuration, everything seems ok to me... comparing to other demo's but something clearly is missing.